# Sonata Admin how to read not mapped field?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, sonata-admin

I added fields with the option `"mapped" => false` to a SonataAdmin form.

Now I need to access the values of the form fields marked with `"mapped" => false` in the method `postUpdate`. How can I retrieve them?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can simply get Form and filed data in your admin class. In method postUpdate:

```
$fieldData = $this->getForm()->get('name_of_field')->getData();
```